# "use quotes instead" error when trying to include SFML library

Tags: c++, include, sfml

I am trying to use the SFML library with

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

but I get the error

```
src.cpp:3:10: error: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
```

If I used angled quotes, it still wouldn't work, because Graphics.hpp includes it's other libraries using the angled include as well, and any example online includes SFML with <>. I am using clang++ on macOS (the same happens with g++), and I imported the SFML folder from the include folder in the SFML install. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you tell the compiler where to find the SFML library?

Comment: @user253751 it's folder is in the workspace, when I change the include to use " quotes, it does work, but like I said then it stumbles on all the angled includes in the Graphics.hpp file.

Comment: You need to add the SFML includes directory (the parent of SFML) to your includes search path.

Comment: <> usually means to look in the system folders first while "" looks in the same folder as your code first. I say usually because this is an implementation dependent feature.

Comment: "" means look in the current directory and <> means look in the places where libraries are. And you can use a compiler setting/flag to tell the compiler where libraries are. Does that give you a hint?

Comment: @paddy That makes sense! As I'm not in an IDE but in VS Code, I was a bit lost on that - what keyword can I google to find how to do it?

Comment: In VSCode you edit your tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json to set the include folder. The reason you edit both is tasks.json is for building and c_cpp_properties.json is for the Intellisense mode. These are completely independent. The VSCode clang documentation describes the 3 json files and their purpose: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! The issue is solved!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `SFML`. To fix this, change `Build Settings` of your Xcode project and add path to where `SFML` library is to `System Header Search Paths`.

[image: Where to specify SFML search path]